# How to apply XSLT 2.0 transformations in .net?

Tags: .net, xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I understand that the .net `XsltCompiledTransformation` class supports only XSLT 1.0 transformations and Microsoft has no plans to even introduce support for XSLT 2.0.

I've looked at software for performing XSLT 2.0 transformations.

The problem is that I need an alternative to Microsoft's `XsltCompiledTransformation` class that will apply transformations on the fly in my program.

Is there a solution out there that does what I want?  An open-source solution would be great, but a commercial solution could be acceptable, too.

Comment: I disagree with your marking of my question as a duplicate.  In the question you link to, the asker wants to know if MS plans to support XSLT 2.0 in .net.  I knew that the answer that that question is "no" when I asked my question.  I specifically asked about what solution I might use to obtain the functionality that isn't provided in .net.

Comment: I have to agree with the OP.  The duplicate you linked to had answers from 2011 in it.  Something can be a duplicate and still be very out of date. Many of the options offered in the other question may not even exist today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saxon is available for .NET and supports XSLT 2.0.  See http://www.saxonica.com/products/products.xml

Comment: I tried this product and several of the ones linked in related questions.  Saxon seems to work best, and the open-source version does everything I need.

Comment: Thank you. How do I implement it in my current web site?